# Intermediate Value Theorem for function from $[0,1]$ to $\mathbb R^2$

Tags: general-topology

Given $f:[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb R^2$ such that $f(0)=(1,0), f(1)=(-1,0)$ and $f$ is continuous with respect to the standard topologies. How can I prove that there exists $x \in [0,1]$ such that $f(x)=(0,y)$, for some $y \in \mathbb R$?

My attempt to a solution was to consider the restriction of $f$ to the set 
$$A = \{x: f(x)=(y,0) \space \text{for some} \space  y \in \mathbb R\} \subset [0,1].$$

Since $f$ is continuous then its restriction is continuous.

Since the restriction of $f$ to $A$ is "basically" a map from $A$ to $\mathbb R$, it makes sense that I would just need to apply IVT to finish the proof. I'm having issue in formalizing the reasoning that the restriction is "basically" a map from $A$ to $\mathbb R$.

Comment: What if the graph of your curve is given by the upper half of the unit circle?

Comment: Just consider the function $g(x) = (f(x))_1$. It has a zero (why?). This proofs your claim (why?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose such an $x$ does not exist. Then letting $D=\{(0,y), y\in \mathbb R \}$, we have $f([0,1])\subset \mathbb R^2 \setminus D$, which is a union of two disjoint open sets (namely the upper and lower half-plane), and hence disconnected. Then $f$ cannot be continuous or else $f([0,1])$ would be connected as the continuous image of a connected set.

By the contrapositive, you have your claim.

Comment: Thanks for the neat suggestion! Just a quick note, we should have $f([0,1])\in \mathbb R^2 -D$ no?

Comment: Yes indeed, I will correct this

Answer (score 1):

Attempt:

Let $f_i$: $[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $i=1,2$.

$f=(f_1,f_2)$ is continuos iff $f_i$, $i=1,2$ are continuos.

$f(x)=(f_1(x),f_2(x))$.

Consider $f_1$:

$f_1(0)=1$; $f_1(1)=-1$, $f_1$ continuos.

IVT : There is a $p \in [0,1]$ s.t.

$f_1(p)=0$.

Let $y:=f_2(p)$, and we are done.